# MD5 MessageDigest not available in system classloader

Tags: java, classloader

I have a custom classloader and in it's constructor I have the following line.

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
```

When I run my sample main application with my custom classloader as the system classloader, I get the following error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available
at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1504)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1468)
```

Since the security providers come from rt.jar, I was thinking these classes must be loaded by the bootstrap classloader, and so I should be able to use them in my classloader. I can access the MessageDigest class after all. Why are the provider classes not available?

EDIT:

One curious thing I noticed is, while the following fail,

```
getInstance("MD5")
getInstance("MD5", "SUN")
```

this one works!

```
getInstance("MD5", new sun.security.provider.Sun())
```

So the provider classes are loaded by the bootstrap loader after all, but for some reason the lookup fails. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried loaded MD5 as part of constructor in custom class loader and it seems loading fine.

MD5 comes as part of:
import java.security.MessageDigest;

Also I tried SHA - that also works fine for me. 
Probably you can recheck java version - because older version it was not included, or may be you can check by loading other algo. like SHA or something?

My code snippet
    public MD5Test(){
    super(MD5Test.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    System.out.println("here I am..");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: Are you using your custom classloader as the system classloader (java.system.class.loader)?

Comment: Another curious thing I noticed is, while getInstance("MD5") and getInstance("MD5", "SUN") fail, getInstance("MD5", new Sun()) works!

Answer (score 1):

Your custom classloader is probably doing the wrong thing - eg not loading from the extdirs path, or not passing the class load request to the parent so it can do the same.

If you just handle the app class path, but not the ext class path, this is exactly what will happen (I know since I ran into the same issue writing a custom class loader).

The first thing to check is that the class load request is coming in to your class loader as you expect. Is it?

Comment: The request comes within the constructor of my classloader, so it's not even constructed yet. As I see it, the request should go to the classloader of my classloader which should delegate to the bootstrap loader.